# layout like weather app in windows 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am new to Windows 8 Metro apps. I want to design my app layout similar to a Windows 8 default app like a weather and news app that looks the same as the panorama control in Windows phone. How can I achieve that behavior in Windows 8, and is there any built in panorama control for Windows 8?

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach:

http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/a-winrt-behavior-to-turn-flipview-into.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the default template and modify it. It is more or less the same but of course you will need to read up about gridview and xaml styling if you are going to do it on xaml/C# though they did it on html5 if I'm not wrong.